# How to test whether CKEditor dialog has a component?

Tags: javascript, dom, ckeditor

I have implemented a small Java servlet to upload some files using CKEditor's prebuilt dialogs, but I'm facing a small problem: I have multiple prebuilt dialogs and I'd like to fill in the URL fields of any of them when the upload has completed, but not all dialogs have the same ID for this field.

How could I test whether the field 'txtUrl', for example, is present in that dialog so that I can fill it? I have tried by using `CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getElement()`, but even when `setValueOf` fails it still returns valid DOM elements, so I'm running out of ideas to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return dialog field or `undefined` if not found:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement( 'info', 'someFieldName' );
```

Comment: It works the way I expected getElement() to work. I must have missed something when reading the docs. Thank you very much.